# Would one build of next js which uses a CDN that takes control of whole DOM affect the another build when both of them are added to one HTML?

Tags: webpack, next.js, next.js13

I want to generate two builds of next js and combine them into one to test if the first build which makes use of a CDN script that takes control of whole DOM affect the other build's DOM?

I have my build folder like this:

```
.next
    /cache
    /server
         /pages
             /example.js // these files I want to bring in one html for testing
             /index.js.   // these files I want to bring in one html for testing
    /static
        /chunks
        /development
        /webpack
```

What I want simply is use those scripts to load into index.html which has two divs with #id1 and #id2 and see if the first dom would affect the second dom too or not.

The CDN script of first page (which is example.js) takes control of whole dom to update text translations, now I am interested in checking if all these script go together in one html file will the same CDN script also take control over the second script? (that is index.js #id2)